# How do you use a value from a data frame as the for loop iterator in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-loops

I'm trying to set a numeric value from a data frame as the iterator condition in a for loop in R and I cannot get it to work.

The idea of the script is this:

1. Loop through the rows in a data frame
2. For each row, loop through a chunk as many times as a value in the row dictates

For example, I have a data frame called `events` like the following:

```
Row     Event        Years
 1        1           10
 2        2           7
```

I would like to run the following loop to perform the script above:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(events)){
  for(j in 1:events[i,2]{
    print(paste('The event number is',i,'and the year number is',j))
  }
}
```

The outcome I'm looking for would look like this:

```
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 1."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 2."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 3."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 4."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 5."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 6."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 7."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 8."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 9."
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 10."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 1."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 2."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 4."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 5."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 6."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 7."
```

But the result I'm getting is:

```
[1] "The event number is 1 and the year number is 1."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 1."
[1] "The event number is 2 and the year number is 2."
```

For testing purposes, I've tried the following code which works the way I want it to...

```
for (i in 1:nrow(events)){
  for(j in 1:10){
    print(paste('The event number is',i,'and the year number is',j))
  }
}
```

...so I've tried every way I can to replicate the `10` value dynamically.

I'm new to R but I'm not new to programming; I've tried everything from how I'm calling the index, to the type of the value, to setting and getting dimensions using `dim()` to the others listed below:

1. `1:as.numeric(events[i,2]`
2. `1:events$Years[i]`
3. `1:as.integer(events[i,2])`
4. `1:as.factor(events[i,2])`

I think I'm treating the iterator as a single value (like an integer) instead of an R construct like a factor or a vector and that's where I'm missing something. I've also read about using the `apply` function for this type of problem but I'm not familiar with its use so I wanted to try and tackle the `for` loop first.

Does anyone know what I have wrong here? I've been pulling my hair out all day on this!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks your `Years` column is column 3 and not column 2. Are you sure that you're correctly accessing the `Years` value? Checking `str(events)` could help to make sure you understand how the data is structured.

Comment: It would be generally less-risky to do `for(j in 1:events[i,"Years"]) {}` That way the order in the dataset doesn't matter.

Comment: @Marius the row is just for illustration, it's not a column in the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Row     Event        Years
1        1           10
2        2           7")

Count <- do.call("c", lapply(df$Years, function(x) seq(1, x)))
df <- df[rep(df$Event, df$Years) ,]
df <- cbind(df, Count)

paste("The event number is", df$Event, "and the year number is", df$Count)
```

I think the for-loops are not a good idea, if you can vectorize.

Comment: Thanks, @r.user.05apr. I messed with your code a bit to get it to work (my data frame was a little different than the example in the question) but I did get it to work with the sequencing strategy with `lapply` and the appending of the `Count` vector.